# REST or SOAP for fast lookup services on user input?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I'd like to create some kind of location search during user input. The webservice should be contacted during typing of the user input, eg a location name.

So it's clear that there might be lot's of queries one after the other.

The response should only contain a couple of data for each found location, like an `id`, a `fullname` and `geoCoordinates`.

Would you create a `SOAP` or `REST` service for this purpose, and why?

Comment: What kind of client?  Desktop web browser?  Android app?  Something else?

Comment: I recommend a WebSocket connection.

Comment: Desktop web browser, so far.

Comment: What are your non-functional requirements?

Comment: What do you mean? I'd say mostly performance and low latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to XML, JSON is light weight. We have the flexibility of choosing responses in REST API's from normal string, XML to JSON, where as in case of SOAP always it will be SOAP XML. So i would prefer to go with REST.

Coming to differences between REST and SOAP, REST supports only HTTP where as SOAP supports other protocols also apart from HTTP. It always better to go with REST if your protocol is HTTP.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that if your protocol is HTTP that REST is always better. For example if you had to interface with a Bank most use the IFX(Interactive Financial Exchange) XML protocol and most of them run it over HTTP(S). The reasons are that the interfaces are complex and need a proper description via a well modeled WSDL. In this case stating REST is always better than SOAP is not accurate. Your other reasoning is sound.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this service is going to be used on some mobile devices. Also since it is a relatively straight forward request response I would go for REST here with JSON as the protocol.

1. JSON is much more lightweight than XML thus saving on the bandwidth required to request and respond. Data usage is still expensive in some countries on mobile.
2. Its a simple service so it really does not warrant the overhead of creating a WSDL and modelling the XSD in the case of a top down approach. Keep it simple so less things can break.

However without really understanding your requirements these are just hunches.